# error TS2339: Property 'renderComponent' does not exist on type 'typeof RootRenderer'. ​

Tags: angular

I'm getting this error while trying to render this code:

```
RootRenderer.renderComponent({
    id: 'test',
    templateUrl: 'app/test.component.html'
})
```

error TS2339: Property 'renderComponent' does not exist on type 'typeof RootRenderer'.   ​

Comment: Provide us your code, version of Angular and other

Answer (score 0):

you're access instance property from class. if you wanna access `renderComponent` you need create an instance of `RootRenderer` (using Dependency Injection).

btw, `RootRenderer` is deprecated from Angular 4, using `RendererFactory2` instead. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/RendererFactory2-class.html